# change NavigateForFormsPages value to true using CSOM

Tags: list, document-library, office-365, client-object-model

I'm searching for a way to change NavigateForFormsPages property using CSOM but no luck till now. any idea how to do it using CSOM?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently it's not possible. You could vote for the feature here:
https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329220-sharepoint-dev-platform/suggestions/15147108-navigateforformspages-support-in-csom

If you create the list through CSOM, you could add the following to your list schema:

```
<List NavigateForFormsPages="FALSE" ... >
```